# Realm, Pass realm data to another activity through intent

Tags: java, android, realm

Is it possible to pass a realm data from one activity to another through intent?

KC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently no. RealmObjects are not currently Parcelable. You can follow the feature request here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/878

Until then you have the following work-arounds:

1) Use the Parceler library: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#parceler

2) Send a primary key value instead and refetch the object.

Comment: `2) Send a primary key value instead and refetch the object.` I recommend this approach, it works pretty well.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend that as well. It ensures you are always seeing the latest data. Using Parceler will give you a in-memory copy of the Realm data.

Comment: yes, it works pretty well for "managed" instances, but what about unmanaged instances? And what if you don't know at code time if it's managed or not?

Comment: Parceler will work on both un-managed and managed objects. It does this by converting the object to be un-managed.

Comment: @Christian Melchior, Is there any update on "RealmObjects are not currently Parcelable"? Because only for `RealmList`, I have to use `Parceler` to pass `RealmList` between activities.

Answer (score 0):

Pass primary key via intent instead of object and fetch the data in next activity mapping that primary key.